# How do we duplicate a folder on tortoisesvn

Tags: svn, copy, duplicates, directory

I'd basically like to duplicate a folder on my svn branch.

Unfortunately I'm never able to perform it without tortoise thinks this is the same previous folder (so it never wants to add that folder and recognize it as a brand new folder to version).

What I've tried so far is (among tricky procedures):

- copy and paste the folder
- rename it with windows
- add to ignore list
- clean up
- add
- commit (and nothing to declare)

I also tried to copy that folder into a non-versioned folder, clean it up, and then copy it back to that folder, add it, commit (nothing to declare).

Though that first looked a very easy straightforward task to do now I'm only getting mad and mad and have a lot of "ghost" commitment every where in my repository log.

Any help?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you right click and drag the folder in Windows Explorer, you will get the option to "Copy Versioned Items". Or if you don't want the History, use the Export command to get an unversioned copy of the folder, then SVN Add it back in.

Comment: Cheers! But right-click-and-drag was not a feature into my list of common things a user is supposed to know.

Comment: I know, I can't even remember how I found that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Within TortoiseSVN there are additional options when you drag and drop a SVN controlled folder with right mouse button. You need either "SVN Copy versioned item(s) here" or "SVN Copy and rename versioned item here", depending on the situation.